# Is it intended behaviour that TypeScript can unify two instances of a class with different type parameters?

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-generics

I recently encountered a TypeScript behaviour that I didn't expect. I'm trying to understand if this is inherent to the way TypeScript works, or if I should report it as a bug.

The code below defines a class `Plan` which is parameterised on the type of command (`C`) which the plan contains.

```js
class Plan<C> {
  // _w?: C
  constructor(readonly subplans: Plan<C>[]) {}
}

function seq<C>(p1: Plan<C>, p2: Plan<C>): Plan<C> {
  return new Plan<C>([p1, p2])
}

function cmd<C>(cmd: C): Plan<C> {
  return new Plan<C>([])
}

function makePlan() {
  const plan: Plan<string> = seq<string>(
    cmd(5),
    cmd(6)
  )
}
```

[See also on the TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEAK4DsA8BhAfNA3gKGtA9PtAPoDuA-AFzQq7TAD2CEALgE4CuwLDbAFGwCmYACZMQAT2gQOAIwAOiCNXhhk6ANoBdAJRYAvtkPYAZhwTcAlk2mCAjqjR95ARhWJHAGmjyATO7VHHQD1DBw8IRYONgRoBEFSOA90Pg1Xbz9dI2xTcysbYABbEUc%20IpFqFGCkwPQsOkjo2PjE1VDUrOMzCxZrWMKwAGtBNr49cPomVh9EEKRWNksEAHMMAF5bBwWl1b46PHK%20AFYdT336Yr4ANh06W-0gA)

Notice that this code compiles fine, despite that:

- The function call `cmd(5)` produces a value of type `Plan<number>`
- The function call `seq<string>()` only accepts parameters of type `Plan<string>`.

It seems that this is caused by the `Plan` class not actually exposing any public properties which use the type parameter `C`. If I uncomment the second line to add an optional property of type `C`, the compiler suddenly springs into action and finds the problem.

Is there a way to rewrite this code (besides adding the phantom parameter as above) so that the mismatched types cause a compiler error?

Comment: TypeScript is _structurally_ typed, so in the absence of anything that actually differs between a `Plan<string>` and `Plan<number>` they're compatible. (And yes, that's intentional: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html)

Comment: I suspected as much - thanks. That said, I would still be interested to know of any other techniques (if they exist!) to prevent the compiler from unifying the two.

Comment: It's not unifying them. They're separate, but compatible, and only because the example's so trivial; if they did anything with the generic type they wouldn't be.

Comment: If someone writes an answer here they might want to link to [this FAQ entry](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-is-astring-assignable-to-anumber-for-interface-at--).  The techniques for how to fix it depend strongly on the use case; right now there's no obvious reason why you'd want them to be incompatible, since `C` never gets cashed out anywhere observable.  Maybe you could [edit] with a more motivating example for why having them be compatible does something observably bad?